# Change logo from admin back-end and login dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin, log, dashboard

I am trying to change logo from Dashboard and Admin login page .Of course I tried all solution from stack overflow . but I am getting the below Error :

> error"Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified
>   key: 'Adminlogo/Changelogo'"

**Step1:app/code/Adminlogo/Changelogo/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Adminlogo/Changelogo</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**step-2:app/code/Adminlogo/Changelogo/etc/module.xml**

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <module name="Adminlogo_Changelogo" setup_version="1.0.0">
         <sequence>
             <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
         </sequence>
     </module>
 </config>
```

**step3:app/code/Adminlogo/Changelogo/registartion.php**

```
    <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Adminlogo_Changelogo',
        __DIR__
    );
    ?>
```

**step4:app/design/adminhtml/mythem/logotheme/registration.php**

```
    <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
        'adminhtml/mythme/logotheme',
        __DIR__
    );


    ?>
```

**step-5:app/design/adminhtml/mythem/logotheme/theme.xml**

```
    <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
        <title>astrokapoor astrology</title>
        <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
    </theme>
```

**step6:design/adminhtml/mythem/logotheme/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_login.xml**

```
        <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <update handle="styles" />
            <body>
                <referenceBlock name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/my_logo.png</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
            </body>
        </page>
```

**step7:design/adminhtml/mythem/logotheme/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml**

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="header">
                <referenceBlock name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument> 
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
                        <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                        <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/astrokapoor_logo.png</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Please follow below URL***

[How to change admin Logo & Backend Logo in M2](https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-admin-theme)

Comment: MR.R DNATH@Thanks But I have done this .with  magento stack-exchange prvious answere

Comment: okay, great.........